# Easiest Java image processing solution

Tags: java, image, api

Here is the deal, in my Java project I have to make a composite document that combines both text and images; So I'm looking for a way to manipulate pictures (rotate, change size, that sort of thing). The API I'm looking for should be clear and easy to learn (preferably with some examples), it should cover the basic transformations I made above - rotate,change size, eventually crop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [java2d api](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/index.jsp) let you do this kind of thing. Is it too difficult to learn?

Comment: No, it isn't. I'll see if there are any other answers. If not than this is the winner.

Answer (score 3):

If you want some more advanced functionality, [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) is a create image library. It's open source and has plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1):

the standard API allows for all your needs.
You can find examples [here](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/ultimate-image/).

Comment: You're welcome. i find it simplier to learn by reading and extending examples. *Then* you can understand most of the docs :)